# Python Web Server UTF8 encoding

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, character

I'm trying to send some data to my Python Web Server through POST, the problem is that the data contains special characters.

I printed it's data to the browser back, but im getting this:
Sent data: text with spécial
Received Data: text with sp\xc3\xa9cial

I have already set the code to # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- and tried to encode or decode the string to UTF-8 but the browser receives only it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what kind of problems you're running into?

Comment: If I print "spécial", it appears OK in the browser. But if it has been sent and passed through parse_qs, the print cant decode it anymore

Comment: Could you show some related codes?

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I just figured out that it was a list instead of string, print wasnt decoding it because of that I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b'sp\xc3\xa9cial'` is a valid Python bytes literal. You could decode it into Unicode string (`.decode('utf-8')`), to get `u'spécial'`.

A likely reason is that you've printed a compound structure such as list that contains the bytestring. `repr()` is called on individual items:

```
>>> print 'spécial'
spécial
>>> print ['spécial']
['sp\xc3\xa9cial']
```

`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` defines the *source code* encoding. It has nothing to do with character encoding at runtime.